# yii ACL for different user roles

Tags: yii, acl

This question may be basic and has been asked before, but I couldn't find it.
I'm using Yii and I get trouble when differentiating users with action's access.
I have a table called tbl_user, with fields like username, password, and role. When a user login, the system will set the loginAs state with his/her role, for example:

```
$role = "Super User"; //assume we get this role by querying the tbl_user
Yii::app()->user->setState("loginAs", $role)
```

In a controller, there are 4 actions, actionIndex, actionCreate, actionUpdate, and actionDelete. If a super user logins, these 4 action will be available. But if another user with different role logins, for example "administrator", all but actionDelete will be available. I tried this:

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',
            'actions'=>array('index','create','update','delete'),
            'expression'=>'Yii::app()->user->getState("loginAs")=="Super User"'
        ),
        array('allow',
            'actions'=>array('index','create','update'),
            'expression'=>'Yii::app()->user->getState("loginAs")=="Administrator"',
        ),
    );
}
```

**EDITED**

The code above doesn't work. When I login as Administrator, I get error 403 for all 4 actions. **Administrator should be able to access all except "delete"**. Is there another way for this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: echo Yii::app()->user->getState("loginAs"); and check the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth

> The access rules are evaluated one by one in the order they are
>   specified. The first rule that matches the current pattern (e.g.
>   username, roles, client IP, address) determines the authorization
>   result. If this rule is an allow rule, the action can be executed; if
>   it is a deny rule, the action cannot be executed; if none of the rules
>   matches the context, the action can still be executed.

So you should combine all the roles that can execute an action in a single expression i.e.

```
    array('allow',
        'actions'=>array('index','create','update'),
        'expression'=>'in_array(Yii::app()->user->getState("loginAs"),array("Super User","Administrator",...))'
    ),

    array('allow',
        'actions'=>array('delete'),
        'expression'=>'Yii::app()->user->getState("loginAs")=="Super User"'
    ),
```

Also if you follow the link above, you'll see how to implement RBAC in Yii. This can reduce your code to something like

```
    array('allow',
        'actions'=>array('index','create','update'),
        'roles'=>array("Super User","Administrator"),
    ),
```

Comment: But based on your code, doesn't that mean Administrator can also access actionDelete? The Administrator should not be able to access it.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps my question is not clear enough, I have edited it.

Comment: I've updated the answer. You should look at the link for more information.

Comment: Thanks topher, it works. Noted about the link, will look more into it.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that `accessControl` is enabled in you controller filter

```
public function filters()
{ 
    // ...
    return array('accessControl',);
}
```